# How to link custom object "Blog" with the chatter groups?

Tags: chatter-groups

I have a question about the chatter Groups. In my company, we want to create a custom object "Blog" to publisher some news. And is it possible add a custom field to link with "Groups" or "People"? Then users are able to search all the articles related to his groups.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Regards,
Jiahuan